# How to use the findbugs in Rational Software Architect?

Tags: java, eclipse, rational-rsa

I'm working in the middle level of company. I use the Rational Software Architect(RSA)7.5.5 and i want to use the "FINDBUGS" . How can i add the plugin in the RSA. Now i downloaded it . I don't know how to use it ? Could you any one of them give me the suggestion to use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog](http://chappidivenkata.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/using-findbugs-eclipse-plugin-in.html) has sketchy instructions on how to install and use the Eclipse FindBugs plugin with RSA 7.0.  I imagine they would work with RSA 7.5.5.

For more info on how to use the plugin, take a look at [this page](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/findbugs/index.html) ... which includes links to 15 minute demo video.  There doesn't appear to be any "official" documentation site for the plugin.